# How to import XSD schema with Python Suds (version 0.3.6) SOAP library : TypeNotFound exception?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I'm trying to use SABRE travel web services with Python Suds, but one XSD seems not well-formed (maybe namespace is missing in this schema).

```
from suds.client import Client
wsdl = 'http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.wsdl'
client = Client(wsdl, cache=None)
```

Debug trace returns :

```
.DEBUG:suds.wsdl:reading wsdl at: http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.wsdl ...
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.wsdl)
DEBUG:suds.metrics:sax (http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.wsdl) duration: 406 (ms)
DEBUG:suds.xsd.sxbasic:Import:0x7f90196fd5f0, importing ns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07", location="OTA_AirPriceLLSRQRS.xsd"
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQRS.xsd)
DEBUG:suds.metrics:sax (http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQRS.xsd) duration: 504 (ms)
DEBUG:suds.xsd.sxbasic:Include:0x7f90196fdf80, importing ns="None", location="OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.xsd"
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.xsd)
DEBUG:suds.metrics:sax (http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.xsd) duration: 1.363 (seconds)
DEBUG:suds.xsd.schema:built:
Schema:0x7f9019708e60
(...)
DEBUG:suds.xsd.query:(u'MessageHeader', http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader), found as: 
DEBUG:suds.xsd.query:(u'Security', http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext), found as: 
DEBUG:suds.xsd.query:(u'OTA_AirPriceRQ', http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07), not-found
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 11.669s

Type not found: '(OTA_AirPriceRQ, http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07, )'
```

It's logic : Python Suds loads OTA_AirPriceRQ in a "None" namespace.
I read "fix broken schema" Python Suds documentation (https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#FIXINGBROKENSCHEMAs):

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor, Import
wsdl = 'http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.wsdl'
imp = Import('http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ', 'http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.xsd')
d = ImportDoctor(imp)
client = Client(wsdl, cache=None, doctor=d)
```

But script return another exception :

```
.DEBUG:suds.wsdl:reading wsdl at: http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.wsdl ...
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.wsdl)
DEBUG:suds.metrics:sax (http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.wsdl) duration: 617 (ms)
DEBUG:suds.xsd.doctor:inserting: 
DEBUG:suds.xsd.sxbasic:Import:0xe6cf80, importing ns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ", location="http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.xsd"
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.xsd)
DEBUG:suds.metrics:sax (http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.xsd) duration: 1.375 (seconds)
DEBUG:suds.xsd.doctor:inserting: 
(...)
Error maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I don't understand how to use "doctor" functions. Somebody can help me, please ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I just posted a workaround to that Suds ticket. You may want to check it out: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/239#comment:19

Briefly, here's the workaround code:

```
from suds.client import Client
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
c = Client('http://url.to/endpoint?wsdl', cache=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/239 .  I added your example to the ticket.